# $\{x \in H^{\infty} : |x_k-y_k| < \epsilon, k = 1,...,N\}$ is open in $H^{\infty}$ for $y\in H^\infty, \epsilon > 0,N\in\mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I know this question has been asked before, but unfortunately, I didn't find the previous answers helpful enough and I am sharing my work here to get help in solving the problem.

> Let $H^{\infty}$ be the Hilbert cube (the collection of all real sequences $x := (x_n)_{n \geq1}$ with $|x_n| \leq 1$ for $n = 1,2,...$). For $x,y \in H^{\infty}$ let $d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^{-n}}|x_n-y_n|$ be the metric on $H^\infty$. You are given $y = (y_n)_{n\ge 1} \in H^\infty,N\in\mathbb N, \epsilon > 0$. Prove that $S = \{x = (x_n)_{n \geq1} \in H^{\infty} : |x_k-y_k| < \epsilon, k = 1,...,N\}$ is open in $H^{\infty}$.

**My work:**

Take arbitrary $x\in S$, and consider $B(x,r) = \{z\in H^\infty: d(x,z)<r\}$. To show that $S$ is open, **we need to find suitable $r$** such that $B(x,r)\subset S$.

$$d(x,z) < r \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}|x_n-z_n| < r \implies |x_k - z_k| < 2^k r$$

For $z\in B(x,r)$ to get inside $S$, we require $|z_k-y_k| < \epsilon$ for $k = 1,2,\ldots,N$. We know that for $k=1,2,\ldots,N$,
$$|z_k-y_k| \le |z_k - x_k| + |x_k - y_k| < |z_k - x_k| + \epsilon < 2^kr + \epsilon$$

What do I do now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x \in S$.

Let $\delta = \epsilon - \max\{|x_1 - y_1|, \ldots, |x_N - y_N|\}.$ Note that $\delta > 0$.

Now, choose $r = \delta/2^{N} > 0$.

We show that $B(x, r) \subset S$. Indeed, let $z \in B(x, r)$.
As you noted, $d(x, z) < r$ implies that $|x_k - z_k| < 2^k r$ for all $k \ge 1$.
Thus, we get $$|x_k - z_k| < \delta$$
for $k = 1, \ldots, N$. For these $k$, we have
$$|z_k - y_k| \le |z_k - x_k| + |x_k - y_k| < \delta + |x_k - y_k| \le \epsilon,$$
where the last inequality follows by choice of $\delta$.

Thus, we have $z \in S$, as desired.